# PHP set_include_path statement

Tags: php, include-path, set-include-path

I can't quite figure out the meaning of this statement:

```
set_include_path('.'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . '../library/'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . '../application'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

A quick breakdown would be appreciated.

Comment: @yes123, I doesn't have to be, the PATH_SEPARATOR is probably set as `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds the two paths to the include_path so that if you 
include a file "../library/filename.php".
you can do it by

```
include('filename.php');
```

instead of

```
include('../library/filename.php');
```

I suppose this is a part of some framework

It basically adds the folder to the php include path

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note here is that the constant `PATH_SEPARATOR` is a predefined constant which allows for a cross-platform path separator (it resolves to ':' on unix-like systems and ';' on windows).

The following code would also achieve the same result but is a bit easier to read:

```
<?php
$paths = array('.', '../library/', '../application', get_include_path());
set_include_path(join(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
```

or a bit more verbose, but easy to add to:

```
<?php

$paths[] = '.';
$paths[] = '../library/';
$paths[] = '../application';
$paths[] = get_include_path();

set_include_path(join(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
```

Answer (score 0):

**What does php's set_include_path function do?**

It sets a possible location for the php engine to look for files.

**For example:**

I put this in a php file called `cmp.php` under `/home1/machines/public_html`

```
<?php
  print "1<br>";
  require("hello.php");
  print "<br>2<br>";

  set_include_path("/home1/machines/public_html/php");

  print "<br>3<br>";
  require("hello.php");
  print "<br>4<br>";
?>
```

Make a new file `hello.php` under `/home1/machines/public_html`, put this in there:

```
<?php
print "hello from public_html";
?>
```

Make a second new file called `hello.php` under `/home1/machines/public_html/php`, put this in there:

```
<?php
print "hello from public_html/php";
?>
```

Run `cmp.php`, and you should get this:

[image]